# When I close my application my program is still in Task Manager

Tags: c#, .net

When I close my application my program is still in Task Manager. My question is what I have to do to free all resource and to close my program completely?

I have one BackgroundWorked and two Timers, maybe there is a problem.

Comment: Sounds that the background thread is to blame for your app not finishing correctly but we would need to see your actual start up and teardown code to suggest something specific

Comment: Pause it in the debugger and see what it's doing.

Comment: BackgroundWorker uses the .NET ThreadPool - as such, all tasks are executed on background threads, which should abort immediately as you exit your application...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have multiple threads? And if so, do they have the `IsBackground` property set? If not, your application will continue running until all of them exit.

(Also, are you quitting with `Application.Exit()` or another way?)

Comment: I have only one BackgroundWorker, no other threads. I have option to prevent application from closing while BackgroundWorker is working. When he finished the job, then I can disconnect and only after disconnecting I can close application. But as I mention, problem is because program is still in Task Manager.

Comment: Your program will still appear in Task Manager while the background thread is executing. That thread is part of your application's process.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force your application to die, you can trap the main form's close event and use Application.Exit() or some other mechanism. But it's more important to figure out why it's not normally terminating. Did you override any of the form closing events (OnClosing, OnClosed) without calling the base method? Did you join all threads and terminate your background worker?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Server is connected, you have to disconect first!", "Conected on server!",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has stopped all processes and close the program:

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
```

Comment: Yanking the process out from under the app when you hit the 'x' in the corner is not good practice. lets hope you have no unflushed buffers writing any files in any thread, no managed resources which need to be properly disposed of, or transactions open on any database ...